# Fixed Header, Footer, and Sidebars with scrolling content area in center

Tags: html, css

Starting with this [Demo Template](http://jsfiddle.net/kFBuD/91/), I would like to create this layout:

[image]

But I have the following problems:

- The two sidebars are not contained inside the scrollable content div.
- The content div does not take a fixed size
- The scrollable content does not present a scrollbar when it overflows
- It is preferred if the browser's main scrollbar is used

Can someone help me to fix these issues?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Using [`display:grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

This uses several new features of CSS that may or may not be supported in your browser of choice. These include [Grid Layout](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), [CSS Variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), and [`position:sticky`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). CSS Variables can be worked around with static values and Grid/`position:sticky` can degrade gracefully with [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

```css
/* Remove unnecessary margins/padding */
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* Header and footer span the entire width, sidebars and content are fixed, with empty space on sides */
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header"
    "empty_left sidebar_1 content sidebar_2 empty_right"
    "footer footer footer footer footer";
  /* Only expand middle section vertically (content and sidebars) */
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 1fr 0fr;
  /* 100% width, but static widths for content and sidebars */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 400px 100px 1fr;
  /* Force grid to be at least the height of the screen */
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;

  /* Stick header to top of grid */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Ensure header appears on top of content/sidebars */
  z-index: 1;

  /* General appearance */
  background-color: #FCFF34;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Save header height to properly set `padding-top` and `margin-top` for sticky content */
:root {
  --header-height: calc(1rem * 1.5 + 1rem * 2);
}

.sidebar-1 {
  grid-area: sidebar_1;
}
.sidebar-2 {
  grid-area: sidebar_2;
}
.sidebar-1,
.sidebar-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

  /* Styling to match reference */
  background-color: #BC514F;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;

  /* General appearance */
  background-color: #99BB5E;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;

  /* Stick footer to bottom of grid */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;

  /* General appearance */
  background-color: #FCFF34;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: .5rem;
}
/* Save footer height to properly set `bottom` and `min-height` for sticky content */
:root {
  --footer-height: calc(.8rem * 1.5 + .5rem * 2);
}

.sticky-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.sticky-content {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: var(--footer-height);
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--footer-height));
  box-sizing: border-box;

  --padding: 10px;
  padding:
    calc(var(--header-height) + var(--padding))
    var(--padding)
    var(--padding);
  margin-top: calc(0px - var(--header-height));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">Header (Absolute)</div>
<div class="sidebar-1">
  <div class="sticky-spacer"></div>
  <div class="sticky-content">Sidebar 1 Absolute position, Fixed width</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sticky-spacer"></div>
  <div class="sticky-content">
    Scrollable content<br><br>
    line 1<br><br>
    line 2<br><br>
    line 3<br><br>
    line 4<br><br>
    line 5<br><br>
    line 6<br><br>
    line 7<br><br>
    line 8<br><br>
    line 9<br><br>
    line 10<br><br>
    line 11<br><br>
    line 12<br><br>
    line 13<br><br>
    line 14<br><br>
    line 15<br><br>
    line 16<br><br>
    line 17<br><br>
    line 18<br><br>
    line 19<br><br>
    line 20
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-2">
  <div class="sticky-spacer"></div>
  <div class="sticky-content">
    Sidebar 2 Absolute position, Fixed width<br><br>
  line 1<br><br>
  line 2<br><br>
  line 3<br><br>
  line 4<br><br>
  line 5<br><br>
  line 6<br><br>
  line 7<br><br>
  line 8<br><br>
  line 9<br><br>
  line 10
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer (Absolute)</div>
</div>
```

## Scrollbar in main content container

The content box (including the sidebars) can be set to any type of width (percent, pixel, etc). Only the scrollable content area will scroll (sidebars/footer/header will just overflow the box). I'd suggest adding some media queries to break out of the sidebars so content isn't hidden on smaller devices, or set a `min-height` on the content box and a `min-width` on the `body`.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    height: 60px !important;
    opacity:.8;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:600px; /* Sizing - any length */
    padding:60px 0 30px 0; /* Header height and footer height */
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar1, .sidebar2 {
    background: red;
    top:60px;
    bottom:30px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar1 {
    left:0;
}

.sidebar2 {
    right: 0;
}

#scrollable2 {
    background:green;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Always on top: Position Fixed-->
<header>
    header
</header>
<!-- Fixed size after header-->
<div class="content">
    <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width-->
    <div class="sidebar1">
        sidebar-left
    </div>
    <!-- Scrollable div with main content -->
    <div id="scrollable2">
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
    </div>
    <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width -->
    <div class="sidebar2">
        sidebar-right
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Always at the end of the page -->
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

## Using the browser's main scrollbar

While using the browser's main scrollbar is possible, it also causes the sidebars to scroll with the page.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    height: 60px !important;
    z-index:100;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:600px; /* Sizing - any length */
    padding:60px 0 30px 0; /* Header height and footer height */
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */
}

.sidebar1, .sidebar2 {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    top:0;
    padding-top:60px;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar1 {
    
    left:0;
    
}

.sidebar2 {
    right: 0;
}

#scrollable2 {
    height:100%;
    background:green;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Always on top: Position Fixed-->
<header>
    header
</header>
<!-- Fixed size after header-->
<div class="content">
    <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width-->
    <div class="sidebar1">
        sidebar-left
    </div>
    <!-- Scrollable div with main content -->
    <div id="scrollable2">
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
        content-main<br>
    </div>
    <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width -->
    <div class="sidebar2">
        sidebar-right
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Always at the end of the page -->
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. A guestion. Is it possible to scroll the scrollable div from outside the div? I mean wherever you scroll inside the page I want it to scroll the scrollable div. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes and no (well, not in the amount of time I have). Using the browser's main scrollbar makes it so the sidebars scroll as well. This may be fine with you, I'm not sure. I've added the jsFiddle example to my answer.

Comment: this was perfect for what I was trying to do. Thanks

Comment: is there any php template like your example.if yes please share the link.thank you in advance

Comment: I suppose during the scroll, contents do not pass behind the top bar but they end their visibility when they touch it. Is it possible to have visibility?

Comment: @helloB The first and third variants I provided both pass the content behind/under the header/footer. That is, if you change the opacity of the header/footer to something like `opacity: .8`, you'll see the sidebars underneath of them. The second variant stops the containing box at the edge of the header/footer. If you want the header to only be part of the main column, put it inside the main column with something like `position: sticky; top: 0;` and it will remain at the top, the main column will scroll behind it, and the sidebars will extend to the top of the page.

Comment: I wonder how does facebook then uses the main browser scrollbar for scrolling main content WITHOUT scrolling the sidebars?

Comment: @SabaAhang Facebook's current header (everything in `<div role="banner">`) is positioned with `position: fixed`. The left/center/right columns are contained in a box that is offset with `position: relative; top: 56px`. This is one way of doing it, but you must be *very* careful not to add content to the header that is taller than the container, or if you do, adjust the offset accordingly. Additionally, offsetting the body with `position: relative` means some content can be cut off, so you have to watch out for that. (I've personally seen the fb layout messed up by these issues in the past.)

Comment: As for Facebook's sidebars having their own scrollbars, they're separate boxes with `overflow: y`. And they stay in place with `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
1.Add `position` property as `absolute` for the div you wish to fix .
2.Keep the body `overflow` property `auto`.

Note: setting the z-index of the body to -1  will make the rest of body inaccessible.
Reference : http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.