# Create a scrolling div between two fixed div elements

Tags: css, html, position

I'm kind of new to positioning divs how I want them in a website, so I hope someone can help here.  What I'm trying to get is a sandwich-type set up with a scrolling content in the middle of two divs.  Such that I have a header div and a footer div, both of which have to stay static on the page.  Then, between them, I have to have a content div that fills the space between the two fixed divs and have the ability to scroll on it's own.  How would I go about building something simple like this?  Or is this not simple at all?

Update: I created a fiddle that I think is ALMOST what I want.  I have the header and footer staying static on the page.  However, I'm having to trick the top margin of the main div so that it's content starts right after the header.  The only problem I still have, really, is that the end of the content is being cut off at the bottom by the footer.  I need to see the entire content.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgskS/18/

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056583/fixed-header-footer-and-sidebars-with-scrolling-content-area-in-center/10056827#10056827

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.  What I need is for the header and footer to be divs and to stay completely fixed, no matter what, while the main content of the page scrolls between them.  What this is doing is creating the a header and footer and somehow creates a margin at the top of the page that creates a new scrollbar.  There should be only one scrollbar on the page.

Comment: @CrystalBlue, you skipped the "Using the browser's main scrollbar" section. Here's an adjusted version, for your exact needs: http://jsfiddle.net/kFBuD/520/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the height of the consecutive elements to equal 100% and set your content DIV to scroll on the Y-axis:

```
<header>
    <h1>Sandwich Layout</h1>
</header>
<div id="main" role="main">

</div>
<footer>
    Footer stuff here
</footer>

html,
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; } /* This is important */

header,
footer { background: #ccc; height:20%; }

#main { height: 60%; overflow-y:scroll; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/3E8Gg/

2020 UPDATE:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>Sandwich Layout</h1>
</header>
<div class="main" role="main">
  <div class="fake-height">Content here</div>
</div>
<footer>
    Footer stuff here
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 0; // prevents flex box expanding out of view-height
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 1rem;

  .fake-height {
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/kboucher/pen/dyomxWN

Comment: This is close to what I need, but I can't get it to work in my website.  When I use your code, I'm getting a small section or margin at the top and it creates a second scroll bar to the right.

Comment: what if you want your header and footer divs to take up a minimum amount of space?  20% for example might be way more than is needed, but the actual amount could depend on how the page is rendered, for instance a narrower window might cause spill and thus need more vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your header and footer divs to fixed, you can make a main div for your content which will scroll the way you want it to.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all the code you've got, but you may need to do a bit of CSS resetting to make it work. (I've set margin and padding to zero in the first CSS declaration above. See if that does anything for you.)