# Creating a relatively positioned scrolling div

Tags: css, html, position

I am trying to create an effect where I have a small header on a page which always remains visible at the top, followed by the rest of the page which can scroll up and down.

At the moment the header scrolls off the page as soon as the page is scrolled, which is not what I want.  I thought about making the second part of the page a scrolling div, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789492/create-a-scrolling-div-between-two-fixed-div-elements), but unfortunately that approach seems to require that I know ahead of time the height of my header div and I do not - the reason being that it is possible the height will change based on the width of the page, so if the page is not wide enough part of the header will spill onto the next line.  For this reason absolute position also seems out of the question, as I can't know ahead of time where the position of the second div will be - it should just come right after the first div, no matter where it is, i.e. relative position but it seems absolute positioning is part of the trick to make a scrollable div work.

So how can I achieve a scrolling DIV that is positioned relative to another element on the page using only CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the header element with:

```
position: fixed;
```

That will make it "fixed" relative to the browser window, regardless of how much you've scrolled.

Comment: Now the start of my second div is overlaying the first div

Comment: You should add a margin-top to the second div that is equivalent to the height of the first div.  e.g. `margin-top: 100px;`

Comment: The height of the first div isn't fixed.  It could change due to browser width causing the contents to spill, or any number of other things.

Comment: You can't do it with CSS.  Once you specify `position:fixed;` the element is taken out of the document flow.  You'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery to set the top margin of the second div.

Comment: i was afraid you would say that.  that means then i will have to trap every event that could result in the height of the first div changing and then recalculate ever time too...

Comment: Yeah...unfortunately there is no listener for a DOM change event (yet).  DOM3 will add some of this.  In the meantime, I'd suggest that you try to consolidate the number of places that you update the fixed header's content so that they all go through the same function (which also updates the top margin of the second div).

Comment: Ok, I've found a way that seems to work.  If I make the second div position:fixed, (not the 1st) and then set it's height to 100%, it somehow knows to not include the first regular div in the height, and to give the second div a scrollbar on overflow:auto (which was what was not happening before).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, taking @zigdawgydawg's answer as inspiration I found that this code will work.

```
<!doctype html><html style="height:98%;">
<body style="height:100%;">
<div> ... contents of first div ... </div>
<div style="position:fixed; overflow:auto; height: 100%;">
... 
contents of second div 
...
</div>
</body></html>
```