# Create a scrolling div between two divs

Tags: html, css, iframe

First of all, yes I've read a lot of subjects about this problem, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789492/create-a-scrolling-div-between-two-fixed-div-elements) is almost exactly what I want.
The only problem is I get the whole to get scrollable, when I only wan't the middle-div to be scrollable.

Maybe it's due to the fact I use it in an iFrame ?

This is the HTML of my iFrame :

```
<div id="chat">
<div class="row-1" id="header" style="height: 20%">
    <span>Live chat</span>
</div>
<div class="row-1" id="message" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 60%">
    <ul id="messages" class="list-group"></ul>
</div>
<div class="row-1" id="footer" style="height: 20%" >
        <input type="text" id="myMessage" placeholder="Type a message">
        <a id="sendbutton" href="#" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> </a>
</div>
```

What I want is to do a little chat icon, in bottom-right corner, that will, when clicked, expand into a little iFrame, displaying the chat :)

But I can't get only the middle div to be scrollable ...

Example of what I want : https://alpha.hacklyon.com/
The chatbot icon the bottom right corner, when you expand it, it's exactly what I want !

Comment: Could you please show the CSS that you've tried?

Comment: Well, I got no CSS, all in the HTML, I'm just trying to make it work, will clean it up after ! :/ So you got everythin, oh, just the iFrame : 
`<div id="chat_icon" style="position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 4%; margin-right: 4%";>
    <div class="collapse" id="iframe_holder" >
      <iframe src="http://localhost:5000/chat" ></iframe>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-circle" data-target="#iframe_holder" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>    
  </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<div id="chat_icon" style="position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 4%; margin-right: 4%" ;>
  <div class="collapse" id="iframe_holder">
    <div id="chat">
      <div class="row-1" id="header" style="height: 20%">
        <span>Live chat</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row-1" id="message" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 120px">
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-group">23232323</ul>
      </div>
      <div class="row-1" id="footer" style="height: 20%">
        <input type="text" id="myMessage" placeholder="Type a message">
        <a id="sendbutton" href="#" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-circle" data-target="#iframe_holder" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that's what I want !
Thanks a lot mate !

Answer (score 0):

```
 #chat{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div id="chat">
  <div class="row-1" id="header">
      <span>Live chat</span>
   </div>
   <div class="row-1" id="message">
   </div>
   <div class="row-1" id="footer" style="height: 20%" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I already tried this, and I can confirm this doesn't work, footer and header are not always visible, and the scroll bar is on the whole chat div ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 #chat{
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
}
#message{
     height: 200px;
     overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Live chat title and input will fixed, and Content will scroll

Comment: Sorry mate but no :'( I already tride this too, as it was for me the logical way to do, but puttint the `overflow-y : scroll` on the message div was not enough, as the whole chat div keep being scrollable.