# height space is not being preserved between partial view changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a mvc asp.net c# app.

I have a page and a user can click a button.
the button click event calls my jquery function which returns a partial view using the div.Load method.
I fadein the second view.

I also have a permanent footer defined in my _layout file.

I have noticed that when the user clicks the button 
the 1st page disappears
the 2nd page fades nicely in
But, between the 1st page dispapearing and the 2nd page starting to fade in my footer jumps up to fill the gap.

I have tried setting the min-height on the container div but still the footer momentarily jumps up.

How should I manage this?

the important part of my _layout page:

```
   <div class="container body-content" style="min-width:1000px; max-width:1000px;min-height:423px;">&nbsp;
        <div id="mainContent" style="height:423px; ">
            @RenderBody()           
        </div>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <div id="divFooter" style="font-family:DIN; font-size:14px;float:right;margin-right:50px;margin-top:50px; ">
                <img src="images/facebook.png" />
                <img src="images/linked.png" />
                <img src="images/twitter.png" />
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

the jquery script to handle the transition:

```
$("#divProductsBanner").click(function () {
    var url = '/Products';
      $('#mainContent').css('display', 'none');
    $('#mainContent').load(url, function () { $('#mainContent').fadeIn(1000); $('#divFooter').css('display', ''); })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Looks like your footer is just "under" the main content, not fixed to the bottom.  Safest option is to fix the footer via css to the bottom.   Alternatively, you could put a "loading" image in your mainContent ie instead of hiding the mainContent, you replace its content with the loading image (or text), then it will always be the same size and your footer won't jump around.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, I did think about a place holder but would you know the css to fix to the bottom please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056583/fixed-header-footer-and-sidebars-with-scrolling-content-area-in-center

Comment: I had just got there myself. But thank you :)

Comment: http://codexsquare.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/aspnet-mvc-and-css-how-to-keep-footer.html

Comment: cool - I shall take a read. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to replace the content of `mainContent` rather than hide it:

```
$("#divProductsBanner").click(function () {
    var url = '/Products';
    $('#mainContent').html("<div style='width:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto'>loading...</div>");
    $('#mainContent').load(url, function () { $('#mainContent').fadeIn(1000); })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes i would use this if I would a 'progress caption' but I do not. I prefer a white space really. But thanks