# Is it possible to make a site where only the middle content column scrolls rest all around is fixed in Wordpress Elementor?

Tags: css, wordpress, web, elementor

[image: PAGE LAYOUT]

Ideally there will be a header and footer at the top and bottom respectively and two side bars one on the left and other on the right and in between all this is the content column which may or may not be longer than one screen height so I want to make only that column scrollable and rest of the elements like the header, footer and the two side bars to remain fixed. Please suggest ways to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add expected result image.Can you create [a minimum reproduciable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). and also read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I understand from the downvote that this is fairly obvious thing for other users. I am not trying to become a professional. I am only trying to build the basics of this so a professional can understand what i want and build it using professional tools. Please ignore post if this is too basic but please guide me on the search terms i can use to find the solution. Every attempt with my limited knowledge only brings up tutorials that i have already watched

Comment: This is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056583/fixed-header-footer-and-sidebars-with-scrolling-content-area-in-center

Comment: use   `position: fixed;top:0` to make fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

That does look very similar to my question.. However I found some tiny code that i can place in the central scrolling column to execute just what i wanted. I found these lines of codes from this very valuable site.
The code is as follows:

```
.scrollcol {
  max-height: calc(85vh  - 20px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
 .scrollcol::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 

}
```

In the code sample instead of 20px it was 9rem. i have no idea what that is.. But 20px works for me at the moment.
Eventhough that piece of code does everything i want.. theres however a scrollbar in the x and y axis.. so the second bit of code removes that on Edge browser.
I am thankful to this site for immense help.
@ Mr. Rayees AC many thanks for your quick response I am looking at that page that you provided for additional help.